# RubyMine Cannot Create Git Branch

Tags: git, rubymine

I have a Ruby project in RubyMine with Git integration enabled. I want to create a new branch. The [help file](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/creating-a-new-branch.html) tells me to open the branches menu and select "new branch". But when I follow the steps to open the branches menu I get a tiny box with the title "Git Branches", the text "nothing here", and in the frame at the bottom it says "Current branch: master" (well, that makes sense at least). There are no menu items, and no "new branch options". Also, the help says that this is easier with the version control window open, but that's disabled on the View menu.

So how *do* I create new Git branches from within RubyMine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this and I only get the "nothing there" message in the branches menu if I just initialized the git verisoning and added none of my files to git.

Open your "changes" tab at the bottom and select the "local" subtab, there you will see your files are listed under the "unversioned files" node.

Add the desired files to GIT, but as a first advice be sure to add all the files under the .idea folder and all *.iml files to the git ignore list. you don't want these versioned.
(try secondary click and then use the ignore option...)

After adding your files, commit them to your repository and you will be able to create branches. There is no sense in making branches of empty contents.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I already had stuff checked in, but I didn't.

Comment: Your are welcome and we ought to be thankfull for the jetbrains guys to keep all of this consistent through all their products. Itested this in intellij...